# Javascript: How to insert a hole into a sparse array or creating a hole

Tags: javascript, arrays, sparse-matrix

I'm using sparse arrays to be memory efficient with huge datasets. (and to signal the difference between a hole and a `undefined` or `null` entry) adding holes at the end is fine by setting `datapoints.lentgh`.

```
datapoints = [10,,,20,,,10,1]
```

No I face the problem how to insert a hole (say before 20)

```
datapoint.splice(3,0)
```

does not work, and I can't find a (easy) method to insert holes. (Think I have to rebuild the array but thought to ask before)
Or is there a way to change a "defined" entry into a hole? `delete datapoint[4];` creates an undefined entry not a hole :(

Comment: OK think I found a solution:

Answer (score 0):

Your sparse array is actually an object. You can delete items and you can add items.

Let's suppose you want to add `k` holes before position `offset`. Then:

```js
datapoints = [10,,,20,,,10,1];
function addHoles(offset, k, datapoints) {
    let migration = {};
    for (let key in datapoints) {
        let intKey = parseInt(key);
        if (intKey >= offset) {
            migration[intKey] = datapoints[intKey];
            delete datapoints[intKey];
        }
    }
    for (let key in migration) {
        let intKey = parseInt(key);
        datapoints[intKey + k] = migration[intKey];
    }
    return datapoints;
}
console.log(addHoles(3, 3, datapoints));
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I could work with

```
datapoint.splice(3,0,undefined);
delete datapoint[3]
```

It looks like that I have a hole now ....